# Can I view my application code from my phone?

Tags: swift, uikit

All the code of my application was removed from the computer due to my stupidity and cannot be restored (I tried everything). But before deleting it, I ran it on the phone and, in theory, all the code is still there. The application was not published in appStrore.

P.S. Sorry for the mistakes, I am writing this text with the help of a translator

Comment: Unfortunately all you have on the phone is the binary (your compiled code) and not the source code itself.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not really about programming

Comment: Maybe your code had a remote GitHub repository?

Answer (score 0):

No, the source code for your app is not put on your phone. Only the compiled app is installed on your phone.